# Programmatically edit Dataprep recipe

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

We have a dataprep job to process input file and produce a cleaned file.

We are calling this dataprep job remotely using dataflow templates. We are using python to run a job from dataflow templates.

Since we need to do this for different files, we need to modify the recipe dynamically and execute the job in dataprep.

Is it possible to edit the recipe of a dataprep job from a Python code (Remotely)? If yes, is it possible to trigger a dataprep job from Python code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is not an API for Dataprep as far but [there is in fact a Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/73866647). You might want to give it a star it in order to prioritize it.